# Why is my array not returned in brackets?

Tags: ruby

I have small script I'm working on:

```
while (true)
    s = gets.chomp #String
        if not s
            break;
        end
    values = s.split
    operation = values[0]
    amount = values[1].to_i

    puts values
    puts values.class
end
```

This is the output:[image]

I inputted 'W 400', and the program printed out the array as requested. However, **why is the array not outputted in a brackets format?** **How can I do this?**

Comment: When posting plain-text results, do try and put those in the body of the question as plain-text. Your terminal themes, fonts, and other stuff distract from the question, plus make it harder if not impossible for some people to read: They're dependent on translation tools and screen-readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `#puts` on an array will output each element in that array to its own line. You can output the array, along with brackets, by calling `#to_s` on the array object:

```
puts values.to_s
# => ["your", "array", "on", "one", "line"]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: or just `p values`